# SQL SERVER how to escape special character

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that exists on a linked server and it has a field called name and I want to search a string called Macy's on that field. I am executing this as a dynamic SQL:-

```
declare @Sql nvarchar(2000)
declare @searchName nvarchar(255)

SET @searchName = N'macy''s'
SET @sql = 'SELECT * from crm_opportunity o where o.NAME LIKE ''% ' + @searchName + '%'' ESCAPE '''''' '
exec (@sql).
```

In other words I am trying to escape the single quote. I get the error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 's'.

Any ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `EXEC`, use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and parameterize your query:

```
execute sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT * from crm_opportunity o where o.NAME LIKE ''%'' +  @searchName + ''%''',
    N'@searchName  nvarchar(255)',
    @searchName = N'macy''s'
```

Not only does this help avoid confusing quote escaping, but it also protects you against Sql Injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply and it works. However, can you also tell me how I can do this using EXEC.

Comment: @SaiBand You would need to double up on your quotes in your `@searchName` variable... `SET @searchName = N'macy''''s'`

Comment: @SaiBand Just to clarify, you have to double up the quotes because they need to be escaped twice... after the first assignment, your variable will contain `macys''s`.  You need the variable to have the two quotes so that it will be escaped again when being evaluated by `EXEC`.

Comment: Is it possible for me to do this in the search query instead of the variable.

Comment: @SaiBand Not really.. the quotes need to be between the `macy` and `s`.  Nothing surrounding the variable in the rest of the `EXEC` statement will do that for you.  I'd really suggest you go with the `sp_executesql` though... The `EXEC` approach is still vulnerable to [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Doubling quotes escapes the character so you use it inside a string value.

```
exec('select *  from [dbo].[UsersTbl] where and  UserType = ''CLT'' ')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11588829)

Comment: ''CLT'' , here the special character is  ' '